# How to replace non-existent elements with 'None' in the list [PYTHON]

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list

```
{"1": "11", "2": "22"}
```

in which there may not be enough data

```
{" 1 ":" 11 "}
```

but in the code I output both 1 and 2.

How to check for elements, and if they do not exist then replace with 
None. 2: "None"

Answer (score 0):

That's a dictionary, not a list

Rather than `data["2"]`, do `data.get("2")`, which returns None if that key doesn't exist